# Template-template, variadic template, and deduction guide: compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, compiler-bug, template-templates

Consider the following heavily templated code:

```
// Preamble
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Rebind template template type traits
template <class> struct rebind_template_template;
template <template <class...> class Template, class... Types>
struct rebind_template_template<Template<Types...>> {
    template <class... Args>
    using type = Template<Args...>;
};

// Rebind template parameters type traits
template <class> struct rebind_template_parameters;
template <template <class...> class Template, class... Types>
struct rebind_template_parameters<Template<Types...>> {
    template <template <class...> class Arg>
    using type = Arg<Types...>;
};

// Template pack
template <template <class...> class... Templates>
class template_pack
{
    private:
    template <class... Args>
    using if_constructible_t = std::void_t<
        typename rebind_template_parameters<Args>::template type<Templates>...
    >;

    public:
    template <class... Args, class = if_constructible_t<Args...>>
    constexpr template_pack(const Args&...) noexcept {}
};

// Class template argument deduction guide
template <class... Args>
template_pack(const Args&...) -> template_pack<
    rebind_template_template<Args>::template type...
>;

// Pretty-printing
template <class Arg>
void print() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    template_pack pack(std::list<int>{}, std::deque<int>{}, std::vector<int>{});
    print<decltype(pack)>();
    return 0;
}
```

What this does, is that it deduces a pack of template templates from its arguments. It works on `gcc` `8` and `9`, but not on `clang`. But I have no idea whether this is even valid C++. Regarless since it works on `gcc` but not on `clang`, one is right, but the other is not. Which one is right?

The error returned by `clang` is:

```
error: pack expansion contains parameter pack 'Args' 
that has a different length (3 vs. 1) from outer parameter packs
```

Note: any simpler code that would reproduce the problem is welcome.

Comment: `template type...` does look suspicious

Comment: I think there is some typo, gcc on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rh2mIR) says `<source>:43:2: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token

 >;`

Comment: @KamilCuk Works perfectly fine for me. Do you compile with `-std=c++17`?

Comment: ` rebind_template_parameters<Args>::template type<Templates>...` for me clang is right, `Args` and `templates` can be different size (and it's the case). I'm not realy sure what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Just do not loose your time to try to compile template code with Clang. Sooner than you think your code will be mangled by work around Clang bugs. Or stay really simple: no template template argument, avoid member template variables, no much trickery with template member specialization, etc... the list is long!!!

Comment: Here's a simpler reproduction: https://godbolt.org/z/AcANVb (no includes, no template template parameters, no ctad, etc.)

Comment: Are you in fact trying to rebind each of a list of input templates with a single template argument drawn from the successive argument types for constructing a `template_pack`?

Comment: Looks like a Clang bug that is related to [this one](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18942).